# SharedPreferences() Method: Password Appears as the Email/Username, as Well

Tags: java, android, authentication, sharedpreferences

In Android, I used the SharedPreferences() method in my login activity. However, the password appears in both fields (password - and username/email). For example, when I ran the activity in an emulator - I inputted an email (ABC@GMAIL.COM) and a password (ABC123); when I exited and re-entered the activity (through the emulator), what has been saved is the password (email: ABC123; password: ABC123).

The code:

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username;
    EditText etPassword;
    Button loginBtn;
    Button registerBtn;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    private static String TAG = "Michael's Tracking --> ";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Log.d(TAG, "Start onCreate");

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        registerBtn = findViewById(R.id.toLoginBtn);

        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mEditor = mPreferences.edit();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
            currentUser.reload();
        }

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String email = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = etPassword.getText().toString();

                String stName = email;
                mEditor.putString(getString(R.string.name), stName);
                mEditor.commit();

                String stPassword = pass;
                mEditor.putString(getString(R.string.password), stPassword);
                mEditor.commit();

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainPage.class));
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent registerPage = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(registerPage);

            }
        });

        checkSharedPreferences();
    }

    private void checkSharedPreferences() {
        String stName, stPassword;
        stName = mPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.name), "");
        stPassword = mPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.password), "");
        username.setText(stName);
        etPassword.setText(stPassword);
    }

}```
````

Comment: [Attach a debugger](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) while saving and getting values to see what values are actually saving in shared prefences

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can use mEditor.commit() once I think you should change this.

And the other one, maybe your strings.xml file is faulty, you can try change these :

getString(R.string.name) -> "name"

getString(R.string.password) -> "pw"